# google-style file for C++ for emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I use the google-style file for emacs. It also looks like a good one to start learning some emacs lisp, not that long. However there is sth I am trying configure in that file, maybe some already did that before, for coding a class, I wrote,

```
namespace A
{
  class A_A
  {
 public:
    A_A();
 private:
    int a;
  };
}
```

however public/private keywords are not at the right places, I did not understand why it places them like this out of the box, how can fix this? I am not good at emacs lisp yet unfortunately.

EDIT: I wanted to have sth like

```
namespace A
{
  class A_A
  {
    public:
      A_A();
    private:
      int a;
  };
}
```

Comment: What is "google-style"?  Sounds like kung-fu.

Comment: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el

Comment: Where do you want the `public:` and `private:` keywords? -- pushed up on the left?

Answer (score 4):

To get indent you like use such debug techniques:

```
(setq c-echo-syntactic-information-p t)
```

When you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> for indenting you will see something like:

```
syntax: ((inclass 33) (access-label 33))
```

As you can see **access-label** identify how indent priv/pub modifiers.
So change to what you want:

```
(defconst my-c-style
  '(
    (c-tab-always-indent . t)
    (c-offsets-alist
     . (
        (access-label . /)  ; XXXXXX LOOK HERE!!!!!!!
        ))
   )
  "My C Programming Style")

(defun my-c-mode-style-hook ()
  (c-add-style "my" my-c-style t)
  ;; If set 'c-default-style' before 'c-add-style'
  ;; "Undefined style: my" error occured from 'c-get-style-variables'.
  (setq c-default-style
        '(
          (java-mode . "my") (c-mode . "my") (csharp-mode . "my") (c++-mode . "my") 
          (other . "my")
          ))
  )
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-style-hook)
```

In example I remove half-level indent as **inclass** add one full indent (to get 1/2 of indent. For offset syntax read <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>c-offsets-alist</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>. For example:

```
  If OFFSET is one of the symbols `+', `-', `++', `--', `*', or `/'
  then a positive or negative multiple of `c-basic-offset' is added to
  the base indentation; 1, -1, 2, -2, 0.5, and -0.5, respectively.
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably nowadays a good solution is given by the config file provided in Github by Google.
In the repository [styleguide](https://github.com/google/styleguide)
there is the config file  [google-c-style.el](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/google-c-style.el)
that, as described in the file,

```
;; Provides the google C/C++ coding style. You may wish to add
;; `google-set-c-style' to your `c-mode-common-hook' after requiring this
;; file. For example:
;;
;;    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)
;;
;; If you want the RETURN key to go to the next line and space over
;; to the right place, add this to your .emacs right after the load-file:
;;
;;    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-make-newline-indent)
```

The file is also distributed via MELT package system as [google-c-style.el](http://melpa.org/#/google-c-style).